# PdfDocument android 11 breaking changes

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I have problems with pdf generated using PdfDocument in the new Android 10.
The output file is not correct.
In the other Android versions, there were no problems.
Any idea?

This is how I generate each page

```
View contentView = pageViewList.get(i);

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width, height, i + 1).create();

        // Start a page
        PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

        // Draw view on the page
        Canvas pageCanvas = page.getCanvas();
        int pageWidth = pageCanvas.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = pageCanvas.getHeight();
        int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        contentView.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
        contentView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
        contentView.draw(pageCanvas);

        // Finish the page
        pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
```

[image]

Comment: `The output file is not correct. I`. There is nothing with a file in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems related to TypedValue.applyDimension that return a wrong value.

```
    pageWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 210, displayMetrics);
    pageHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 297, displayMetrics);
```

So it's not related to PdfDocument.

Comment: so you mean to say instead of pageCanvas.getWidth(); and pageCanvas.getHeight(); use the one above in your  answer?

Comment: It seemed a bug in the Android release. The behaviour improved with the latest Beta release of Android 11.

Comment: I m facing issues with complex layout and to me, can I know how you are calculating width and height which you are passing to the pageinfo builder?